# How to install Splunk for postfix?

Tags: logs, postfix

I'd like to have a dashboard accessible through my apache server which displays postfix logs.

I found [Splunk for postfix](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/933/#/overview), but there is nowhere an Install instruction for it.

Do I need a full Splunk app to run it? Will I be able to display there apache logs as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the *standard* Splunk Light (without any add-ons), and it's enough to display and analyze postfix logs.